# How to remove className and methodName parameters appended to the url on redirect by struts2?

Tags: struts2

I'm working on a struts2 web application with **struts2-core-2.3.4.1.jar**, and I'm using `type="redirect"` on a mapping in my **struts.xml** file. This is my code snippet:

```
<action name="{className}/{methodName}"  class="controller.{1}" method="{2}">
    <result name="setAttribute" type="redirect">
        <param name="location">${sportName}/${locationName}/${year}/${championshipName}/${groupName}/teams/${teamName}/info</param>
        <param name="teamId">${teamId}</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Redirection works fine, but according to what I read on [this webpage](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/redirect-result.html), I expect to get the following url:
*`http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/soccer/italy/2011/serie-a/serie-a/teams/juventus/info?teamId=2`*

Instead, this is the url which appears in my browser:
*`http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/soccer/italy/2011/serie-a/serie-a/teams/juventus/info?teamId=2&className=ControllerTeams&methodName=setAttribute`*,
where *`ControllerTeams`* and *`setAttribute`* are respectively the `className` and the `methodName` matching the action in my **struts.xml** file.
So, what should I do to remove the *`&className=ControllerTeams&methodName=setAttribute`* appended at the end of the url?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: So don't use `namedVariable` pattern matcher. Use wildcards.

Comment: @AleksandrM: Actually, I'm using the following constant value:  
`<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex" />`.  
My problem is when the redirect is performed I just don't want the last two parameters to be appended by default to the new url, but I need to create my new url by using the values of parameters coming from the execution of the method `setAttribute()` from the class `ControllerTeams`...
Can you tell me what shoul I do to reach this goal, how should I modify my **struts.xml** file?

Comment: There was a bug related to that but I cannot find it now, so I don't is it solved or not :\

Comment: Just use default `struts.patternMatcher` and change action name to use wildcards.

Comment: @LukaszLenart: Bug? AFAIK `regex` pattern matcher should do exactly that.

Comment: @LukaszLenart: I'm using struts2-core-2.3.4.1.jar, I've just edited my question to add this info.

Comment: @AlexGpeppe: Have you tried it without `regex` pattern matcher?

Comment: @AlexGpeppe can you try with the latest version?

Comment: @AleksandrM I tried, but after I remove that line, struts can't filter any my actions properly anymore.

Comment: @LukaszLenart: My project is a maven project; I changed my **pom.xml** file, now I'm using **struts2-core-2.3.15.1.jar**, but the behaviour I described hasn't changed.

Comment: @AlexGpeppe: You need to remove `regex` pattern matcher and rewrite your action to use wildcards something like `name="*/*"`.